# Comparing two cells and adding HTML tag to matching values

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have two columns, one with all items in a set and another with the items I currently have. I would like to compare those and for the matching results to have a bit of text added if they match. [Here is an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XK6U9fJVr9cWB8AN9T0UMdsZZl7ajCl6NscB58AuHIY/edit?usp=sharing).

So in that example, Column A is the set number, Column B is the set values, Column C is what I have currently, and Column D is the expected result.

So I want to compare B to C and if there are names matching, then I want B to have this `<img src='tick.svg'>` appended to the matching name.

Got some help working on this with the following function:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN("<br />&#10 ", 1, REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2, "<br />&#10"))), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, IF(REGEXMATCH(TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2, "<br />&#10"))), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(C2, "<br>"))))), 
 TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2, "<br />&#10"))), )), TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2, "<br />&#10")))&" <img src='tick.svg'>")))
```

However when I have `'<br>'` tags or `'<br />&#10'` in the cell it will skip or replace certain words (e.g. *row 2 col E*). Also, I currently have to drag it to the next cell, it would be handy to make it apply to each row automatically,

Note: It links to this [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130816/comparing-two-cells-and-adding-text-to-matching-values) in web applications, that was solved but has a bigger scope.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

paste in **D2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISNUMBER(
 QUERY(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(IF(IF(REGEXMATCH(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(IF(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ",")<>"", "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&
 TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ","))), )))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♠"))),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(IF(
 SPLIT(C2:C, ",")<>"", A2:A&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(C2:C, ","))), ))),,999^99)),,999^99))
 , " ", "|")), TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(IF(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ",")<>"", "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(
 SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ","))), ))),,999^99)),,999^99),
 "♠")))&" - CHECK", )<>"", IF(REGEXMATCH(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IFERROR(IF(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ",")<>"", "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ","))), )))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♠"))),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(IF(
 SPLIT(C2:C, ",")<>"", A2:A&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(C2:C, ","))), ))),,999^99)),,999^99)),
 " ", "|")), TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(IF(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ",")<>"", "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(
 SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ","))), ))),,999^99)),,999^99), 
 "♠")))&" - CHECK", ), TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(IF(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ",")<>"", "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(
 SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ","))), ))),,999^99)),,999^99),
 "♠")))), "♦")), "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0)), INDEX(QUERY(IFERROR(SPLIT(IF(IF(REGEXMATCH(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(IF(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ",")<>"", 
 "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ","))), )))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♠"))),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(IF(SPLIT(C2:C, ",")<>"", A2:A&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(C2:C, ","))), )))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99)), " ", "|")), TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IFERROR(IF(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ",")<>"", "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ","))), ))),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")))&
 " <img src='tick.svg'>", )<>"", IF(REGEXMATCH(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(IF(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ",")<>"", 
 "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ","))), )))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♠"))),SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(IF(SPLIT(C2:C, ",")<>"", A2:A&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(C2:C, ","))), )))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99)), " ", "|")), TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IFERROR(IF(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ",")<>"", "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ","))), ))),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")))&
 " <img src='tick.svg'>", ), TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(IF(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ",")<>"", "♠"&A2:A&"♦"&
 TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B, " <br />&#10", ","), ","))), )))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")))), "♦")), "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 
 pivot Col2", 0), 1, ), ), " ", "♂")),,999^99))), " ", " <br />&#10 "), "♂", " "))
```

[image: 0]